# Specific processes sharing memory via mmap()

Tags: memory, linux-kernel, shared-memory

My question is simple How do I share memory among processes allowing reads and writes of memory .The main thing is only specific processes(like specific PID's for example) should have the ability to share that memory .Not all processes should have the ability to share the memory.

Comment: See [Is it possible to share memory between Linux processes?](http://qr.ae/Ri9exd).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use the standard Sys V IPC shared memory. After call to shmget(), use shmctl() to set the permissions. Give read write permission to only one group/user and start the processes which are allowed to access this as the specific user. The shared memory key and IDs can be found using ipcs, and you need trust the standard unix user/group based security to do the job.

Another option is implementing a shared memory driver. Something similar to Android ashmem. In the driver, you can validate the PID/UID of the caller who is trying to access the memory and allow/deny the request based on filters. You can also implement a sysfs entry to modify these filter. If the filters needs to be configurable, again you need to trust the Unix user/group based security. If you are implementing a driver, you will have plenty of security options